# Issues Using py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe

So I ran py2exe with a piece of code like

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['WorkingPSI_J.py'])
```

and the console did everything it should have (I don't seem to have any errors).  Afterward however I got no build or distribution folders.  Did I miss something simple?  Thanks in advance.

edit:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\untitled-22.py", line 4, in <module>
    setup(console=['WorkingPSI_J.py'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 140, in setup
    raise SystemExit, gen_usage(dist.script_name) + "\nerror: %s" % msg
SystemExit: usage: untitled-22.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: untitled-22.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: untitled-22.py --help-commands
   or: untitled-22.py cmd --help
```

I noticed upon running it a second time that it tells me it's 'skipping' a lot of things.  Does anyone know how to fix that sort of issue?

Comment: What output did you get after running your script?

Comment: I've put what I think was an error when running the script through IDLE.  No errors when running  filename.py py2exe though.

Comment: @Qiu Is the first piece of code I posted generally okay for taking a tkinter script and making an exe out of it in one go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to compile your script using IDLE. When you are using `py2exe`, you have to do it a little bit different.

If you've used Disutils before, you might have seen this:

```
python setup.py install
```

The same way you're using py2exe. So type in cmd:

```
python untitled-22.py py2exe
```

And it should work. BTW I recommend you reading [this](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) tutorial at py2exe.org.

Comment: I just gave that a shot but it gave me the same issue about 'skipping'.  Again I'm not sure if that's an issue but no folders came up on the desktop.  I'm doing this from the directory C:\Python27 if that helps.  It's definitely not an issue with the code right?  If I used that code to try to make an exe for any python program it would work?

Comment: @Stopwatch: if you open the tutorial I recommend you, you'll find expected output. Did you get similar? Did you check if C:\Python27\dist\ was not created?